# Is it possible to use symbols instead of colours to visualise raster cell values?

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, visualisation

I have a raster image (GeoTIFF) with *integer* values. I know how to visualise raster values in QGIS using colormaps or similar, but I would like to assign symbols to each colour value instead - just like a colormap, but with symbols.

**Example:**
[image]

**Question:**
Is this possible and in that case how?

Comment: well, you can use SVG symbols in colormaps, which will give some nice looking maps

Comment: Can you give me a hint to where I can learn about this?

Comment: Using Curfew's answer I think I would work on getting each cell converted to a point (much like asc grid) to control the 1 symbol per value. But I don't see how you can get around converting to vector.

Comment: It might be possible, but I think we need to know more about your raster. Is it really an *image*, how many bands does it have and how many "colors" does it have? N.

Comment: In this case my raster is a one band image with 10 different integer values - a simple case. But it could be neat to be able to style raster images on the fly in general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Polygonize your raster shape via the Raster-to-polygon tool in the raster menu. Use your field value as category
2. Click on categorized styling, classify and double click on the symbol. Then select "SVG-FILL" and the following dialog should appear with some basic SVG icons coming with QGIS. 
   [image]
3. Choose an icon and remember to set the border line ("simple line") to no-pen. Otherwise the fields will be bordered with a small line. Your question displays such border line, so maybe you want to keep them.
4. Apply and gaze upon your new styling. You could ease up the styling a lot, if you use rules and categories. 
   Here a quick example of a forest with surrounding plains. The polygon was generated from a forest cover raster layer. [image]

This was done using the QGIS 1.9 Development Version, but is assume it should be possible in 1.8 as well.  You can style your own SVG-Symbols using for instance the excellent [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) suite

Comment: I fine solution. But I really prefer one where I don't have to alter my raster, in your example, to polygonise it.

Comment: this could be very hard to realize, because as far as i know raster cells can only be displayed with RGB-colors. Something as complex as symbols clearly belong to the world of vector layers

Comment: A raster is just a grid, so converting to points rather than polygonizing it might be closer to Chau's requirements.  Then just symbolize the points accordingly and, if needed, lay a simple grid over the top at the same resolution as the raster to make it look exactly like Chau's example picture.

Answer (score 4):

Suggesting your raster is of pretty large scale (landuseage, weather,...), why don't you simply convert them to vector format ?

Comment: Because its a visualisation just like colormaps.

Comment: well, you can use SVG symbols in colormaps, which will give some nice looking maps

Comment: Can you give me a hint to where I can learn about this?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that QGIS still comes with gdal2xyz.py and using this you can convert your raster to a text file.

Open a terminal in the directory containing the raster and run:

```
gdal2xyz.py filename.tif filename.txt
```

The text file will contain space-delimited xyz triplets comprising an *x* ordinate, a *y* ordinate and a *z* value (from the raster).

You will need to add a new first line to the file, something like "x y z" (without the quotation marks). Having done this you will be able to load the file into QGIS using the "add delimited text" tool, selecting "space" as a delimiter.

In QGIS you can then style the points: Properties -> Style Tab -> Categorized and then use font symbols to style the points.

[image]

Comment: interesting example (+1). Is a XYZ-Layer a vector layer and how is this different from polygonizing the raster ?

Comment: Well, if you polygonize a raster what you are doing is making polygons that enclose *groups* of pixels having the same value. But in this case what was required was to explode the raster to vector points, each point having an attribute-value taken from the raster.